# How to integrate artifactory with splunk

Tags: artifactory, splunk

I want to integrate the artifactory with splunk to see the artifactory logs. Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to install a universal forwarder on the artifactory instance to send data back to your splunk indexers.  On the forwarder you would want an inputs config that states something similar to below:

```
[monitor:///opt/artifactory/logs/access.log]
index = artifactory
sourcetype = artifactory:logs:access

[monitor:///opt/artifactory/logs/artifactory.log]
index = artifactory
sourcetype = artifactory:logs:application
```